# コマンドプロンプトでの改行

Tags: ruby

プログラミング超初心者で、Rubyを勉強しています。
とある本のタスクを３つまで設けられるToDo_listを作る例題をやっています。
サクラエディタでコードを書き、コマンドプロンプトで実行しています。

コマンドプロンプトで実行中に、１つ目のタスクをひらがな入力しenterを押しても
２つ目のモード選択に行かず改行になってしまい、もう一度enterを押すと表示されていなかった２つ目のモード選択で入力せずenterを押したと判断され、設定したエラーになってしまいます。半角英数でタスク設定をするとうまくいくのですが。

```
todo_list = [{"締め切り"=>"未設定","タスク"=>"未設定"},{"締め切り"=>"未設定","タスク"=>"未設定"},{"締め切り"=>"未設定","タスク"=>"未設定"}]

puts "【モードを選択】"
puts "[show]ToDoを確認する"
puts "[add]ToDoを追加する"
print "showまたはaddと入力してください→"
mode = gets.chomp!

if mode == "show"
  puts "【ToDo確認モードを選択しました】"
  puts "現在のToDoはありません"
elsif mode == "add"
  puts "【ToDo追加モードを選択しました】"
  print"１つ目の締め切りを入力してください→"
  todo_list[0]["締め切り"] = gets.chomp!
  print "１つ目のタスクを入力してください→"
  todo_list[0]["タスク"] = gets.chomp!
else
  puts "エラーです。プログラムを終了します。"
  exit
end


puts"【モードを選択】"
puts" [show]ToDoを確認する"
puts" [add]ToDoを追加する"
print" showまたはaddと入力してください→"
mode = gets.chomp!

if mode == "show"
  puts "【ToDo確認モードを選択しました】"
  print "1."
  print todo_list[0]["締め切り"]
  print"までに"
  puts todo_list[0]["タスク"]
  print "2."
elsif mode == "add"
  puts "【ToDo追加モードを選択しました】"
  print"２つめの締め切りを入力してください→"
  todo_list [1]["締め切り"] = gets.chomp!
  print"２つ目のタスクを入力してください→"
  todo_list[1]["タスク"] = gets.chomp!
else
  puts "エラーです。プログラムを終了します。"
  exit
end
```

サクラエディタ　ver 2.2.0.1
文字コード　UTF-8
win 10

自分なりに調べましたが、解決に至らずここで初めて質問させて頂きました。
どなたかご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: `gets.chomp!`のある行の前に`STDOUT.flush`を追加してみたらどうなりますか？テキストを表示するのがかなり遅いことなので、何回も短いテキストを表示するより、一度に大量のテキストを表示するのが効果的です。そのため、（プログラム）が表示する予定のテキストをバッファに集めるのが普通です。そのバッファーが十分に満ちていると、一度に大量のテキストが表示されます。`STDOUT.flush`は、バッファーが十分に満ちていなくてバッファの内容を今すぐ表示させるコマンドです。恐らく今の不思議な不具合はこのバッファのためでしょう。

Comment: 気になったのでWindows10の`ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [i386-mingw32]`で試してみたところ`irb`で`gets`の後に`日本語`と入力すると`=> "\xFA\xFF日本語\n"`が返ってきてるようです。@永劫回帰 さんの`STDOUT.flush`も試してみましたが効果ありませんでした。

Comment: コマンドプロンプトでRubyをやると言語学習とは別の大変なエラーがよく起こるので、私としては環境構築が少しめんどくさいですが、Microsoft StoreからUbuntuを入れて、その中にRubyの開発環境を入れるのをおすすめします。

Comment: 関係があるかわかりませんが、 Windows 10 October Update (version 1809) で導入された新しいコンソールの不具合に起因して、**日本語などのマルチバイト文字を表示するプログラムが正常に動作しない不具合**が存在するようです ( [参考](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/3a8a7941-a284-40eb-9588-808c575e7c1b/1249612540124721251912531-1809-12398-os) ) 。解決策は前文で示したリンク先にも書かれていますが、「コマンドプロンプトのプロパティから、レガシーコンソールを使用するにチェックを入れ、再起動を行う」か、「アプリケーションの初期化処理などで `setlocale` 関数等を利用して明示的にロケールの設定を行なう」必要があるそうです。質問者さんが動作確認に使用している OS が Windows 10 とのことなので、参考まで。

Comment: @supa おそらくこれが原因ですね。私の環境では「従来のコンソールを使う」にチェックを入れてコマンドプロンプトを再起動してから動作確認したら正常に動きました。

Comment: @supa おっしゃる通りにやってみたら治りました。ほかの方もいろいろな意見をありがとうございました！！

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[コメントにて解決](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54578/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E6%94%B9%E8%A1%8C#comment58474_54578)されたようなので、改めて回答として投稿しておきます。

---

### 原因

この現象は、 Windows 10 October Update (version 1809) ならびに Windows Server version 1809 で導入された、新しいコンソールにおいて発生する不具合で、出力ストリームに紐づけられた内部的なコードページテーブルの初期化処理に不足があり、**内部処理でマルチバイト文字を正しく認識出来ないことが原因**のようです<sup>[1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/3a8a7941-a284-40eb-9588-808c575e7c1b/1249612540124721251912531-1809-12398-os)</sup>。

---

### 解決策

この不具合の解決策は、以下の 3 つが挙げられます。

#### 1. コンソールにてレガシー コンソールを使用する

上記バージョンからコンソールの仕様が変わり、新しいコンソールが導入されました。今回の不具合は、この新しいコンソールにおいて発生するので、以前のコンソールを使えば問題は解決します。

以前のコンソールは**レガシー コンソール**として残っていますが、これを使用するには、以下のような手順でコンソールの設定を変更する必要があります。

1. コマンドプロンプトを起動
2. 「プロパティ」から「レガシー コンソールを使用する」にチェックを入れる
3. コマンドプロンプトを閉じて再起動する ( パソコン自体の再起動は不要 )

なお、レガシー コンソールを使う場合、**一部の最新機能が使えなくなる**点に注意が必要です。

#### 2. アプリケーションの初期化処理などで、明示的にロケールの設定を行なう

問題の不具合は、初期化処理の不足が原因で発生しているので、アプリケーションの初期化処理で `setlocale` 関数等を利用して、**明示的にロケールの設定を行なう**ことで不具合を解消出来ます。

#### 3. 次期バージョンの OS (19H1) まで待つ

この不具合は既にマイクロソフトが認識しており、次期バージョンで修正される予定となっています。そのため、時期バージョンまで待つことで解決出来ると思います。

また、 KB4490481 (OS Build 17763.404) 以降では既に修正されているという情報があるので、該当の更新プログラムを適用することで解決出来るかもしれません<sup>[2](http://www.hitachi-support.com/alert/us/HWS19-003/index.htm)</sup>。

---

参考:

- [バージョン 1809 の OS 上でコンソール出力が正しく表示されない問題について](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/3a8a7941-a284-40eb-9588-808c575e7c1b/1249612540124721251912531-1809-12398-os)
- [Windows(Version 1809)上でコンソール出力が正しく表示されない問題による製品への影響について：製品使用上の注意事項：日立](http://www.hitachi-support.com/alert/us/HWS19-003/index.htm)