# 開発環境をWindowsからUbuntu(WSL)に移行したところ、LoadErrorが発生する

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, wsl

## 前提

こちらの質問でご指摘を受け、速度の問題で実行環境をUbuntuに変更しました。
[ruby - コマンドプロンプトでの改行 - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54578/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E6%94%B9%E8%A1%8C?noredirect=1#comment58365_54578)

それまでは開発をサクラエディタ、実行をコマンドプロンプトで行っていました。

## 発生した問題

しかしコマンドプロンプトでやっていたようにファイルを実行しようとすると

```
ruby:No such file or directory --ファイル名　(LoadError)
```

と、表示されてしまいます。

手順は

1. Ubuntuを開く
2. 入力待ち（名前@LAPTOP-B5M3JJ58:~$)になる
3. ruby　と入力する
4. 実行したいファイルをドラッグしてくる
5. エンターキーを押す

という手順でやっています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

### 補足情報（OS, ツールのバージョンなど）

- Windows10
- サクラエディタ　2.2.0.1(文字コードはUTF-8で作成)
- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- Ubuntu内のruby 2.5.1p57 [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: エラーが出るまでに行った手順を箇条書きで追記してみてください。 / 現状だと「エラーが出た」しか情報がなくアドバイスは難しいと思います。 / 「速度の問題で」辺りの話は [別質問でのアドバイス](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54578/3060) を受けてだと思いますが、リンクを貼っておくか要約として質問文に含めておかないと「なぜWindowsやサクラエディタの話が出てくるのか」が分かりづらいです。

Comment: 簡潔に言うと、「ファイル名」というファイルが存在しないということです。ファイル名が保存されているフォルダーに移動してからまた「ruby ファイル名」を打てれば大丈夫でしょう。移動するために`cd`を使い、現在どこのフォルダーにいるのを知るために`pwd`を使い、フォルダーの内容を見るために`ls`を使うのが普通です。

Comment: 単に windows ではファイル名の大文字小文字を区別しないのに対して Linux では区別するだけのことでは

Comment: 現在手元にWSLの環境がなくて試せないのですが、「Ubuntuのコンソールにドラッグアンドドロップすると **Windowsから見たパス** が貼り付けられるが、実際には ホストのファイルは `/mnt/c/` などにマウントされているため、ファイルが見つからない、と推測します

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらく Windows 上で WSL の Ubuntu を動かしてらっしゃるのだと思います。

WSL Ubuntu と Windows ではファイルの扱い方が異なり、Windows が認識している「ファイルの場所」と Ubuntu が認識している「ファイルの場所」が異なります。ファイルを Ubuntu 上の Bash へドラッグ＆ドロップすると Windows 側が認識しているファイルパスがペーストされますが、このままだと Ubuntu からは認識できないため「ファイルが見つからない」というエラーになります。

WSL Ubuntu から Windows 側にある Ruby プログラムのファイルを実行するには、以下の手順を辿るのが良いでしょう。

1. `cd` コマンドでプログラムのファイルがあるディレクトリまで移動する。
2. `ls` コマンドで確認する。
3. `ruby 〈ファイル名〉` で実行する。

この際、Windows の C ドライブ `C:\～` は Ubuntu 側では `/mnt/c/～` というパスになっていることに注意してください。たとえば Windows 側のファイルが

```
C:\Users\nek\Documents\example.rb
```

であるなら、Ubuntu 側からは

```
/mnt/c/Users/nek/Documents/example.rb
```

にあるように見えています。このため、各手順では次のようにします。

1. `cd /mnt/c/Users/nek/Documents` で移動。
2. `ls` で `example.rb` が表示されるか確認。
3. `ruby example.rb` で実行。